# Can i find out how much memory a Collection uses?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, memory

I have a Collection of lineEntitys. I would like to see how big the size of it is in memory.

Is there a way of finding out similar to using sizeof(int) to accomplish this?

Comment: At runtime?  At compile time?  At run time using an outside process (such as the CLR Profiler)?

Comment: i would need it at run time, preferably not using an outside process, but i could accept one if it is the best/only way to go.

Comment: Not possibly easily. THe main question would basically waht is part of the collection waht not. Are the objects contained? DO you count them 5 times swhen you sum  up the sapce of 5 collections with the same bojects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1):

> The CLR Profiler includes a number of
>   very useful views of the allocation
>   profile, including a histogram of
>   allocated types, allocation and call
>   graphs, a time line showing GCs of
>   various generations and the resulting
>   state of the managed heap after those
>   collections, and a call tree showing
>   per-method allocations and assembly
>   loads.

Another option is to wrap your allocation in two calls to [GC.GetTotalMemory():](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx)

```
        long memoryUsed = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
```

Also, [Inspect and Optimize Your Program's Memory Usage with the .NET Profiler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188781.aspx)

Comment: This would be very difficult to do at runtime in a programmatic way.

Comment: The question doesn't explicitly say it needs to be performed at runtime, just that the size be determined.

Comment: I concur that the question it is not specific enough, but based on sizeof(int) being used in the question, it might end up being at runtime.  I added a clarifying comment to the question, since solutions can vary a lot.

Comment: Didn't know about this +1
Also there are the source code of this application which shows how it works!